# check whether we can split string in two half and both halfves are equal?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I am working on a project where I need to add below method in `SampleQueue` class - .

```
public static boolean isValid(String s)
```

> Above method should do this - It will take a String as an input
>   parameter. Consider strings that can be split so that their first half
>   is the same as their second half (ignoring blanks, punctuation, and
>   case). For example, the string "treetree" can be split into "tree" and
>   "tree". Another example is "world, world". After ignoring blanks and
>   the comma, the two halves of the string are the same. However, the
>   string "kattan" has unequal halves, as does the string "abcab".

Basically my method should return true when string has the property above and false otherwise. We need to only use methods in `SampleQueue` class as shown below to implement the method:

```
public class SampleQueue<T> {
  private T[] queue;
  private int frontIndex;
  private int backIndex;
  private static final int DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY = 200;

  public SampleQueue() {
    this(DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY);
  }

  public SampleQueue(int initialCapacity) {
    T[] tempQueue = (T[]) new Object[initialCapacity + 1];
    queue = tempQueue;
    frontIndex = 0;
    backIndex = initialCapacity;
  }

  public void enqueue(T newEntry) {
    ensureCapacity();
    backIndex = (backIndex + 1) % queue.length;
    queue[backIndex] = newEntry;
  }

  public T getFront() {
    T front = null;
    if (!isEmpty())
      front = queue[frontIndex];

    return front;
  }

  public T dequeue() {
    // some stuff here
  }

  private void ensureCapacity() {
    // some stuff here
  }

  public boolean isEmpty() {
    // some stuff here
  }

  public void clear() {
    // some stuff here
  }


  public static boolean isValid(String s) {
    if (s == null || s.isEmpty()) {
      return false;
    }
    SampleQueue<Character> myQueue = new SampleQueue<>();
    for (char ch : s.trim().toLowerCase().toCharArray()) {
      if ((ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') || (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9'))
        myQueue.enqueue(ch);
    }
    // all is this right way to check the length?
    if (myQueue.queue.length % 2 == 1) {
      return false;
    }
    // now I am confuse here?
  }
}
```

I implemented few things in the `isValid` method basis on this logic I came up with but I am confuse on what to do for the case length is even?

> Enqueue all of the string’s characters—excluding blanks and
>   punctuation—one at a time. Let the length of the queue be n. If n is
>   odd, return false. If n is even then what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

This seems overly complicated; use a *regular expression* to remove everything not a letter and then test if the two halves of the `String` are equal. Like,

```
public static boolean isValid(String s) {
    String t = s.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]", "");
    return t.substring(0, t.length() / 2).equals(t.substring(t.length() / 2, t.length()));
}
```